# poisson equation- decay rate

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Given a solution $\phi\in C^2(\mathbb{R})$ to the equation 
$$
\Delta \phi=u
$$
If I know that $u\in C(\mathbb{R})$ and $u\to 0$ at $x\to \pm\infty$ faster than any polynomial can I know something about the decay rate of $\phi$?

thank you

Comment: Since this is $\mathbb{R}$, the Poisson equation is just solved by integrating twice. What do you get out of that?

Comment: No information. It can diverge. Is there a familiar condition so also $\phi$ will decay fast?

Comment: It *could* diverge...but this hinges on the boundary conditions that you choose at infinity for $\phi$. Indeed $\phi$ is uniquely determined up to an affine function, because of what I said before.